# List items from different tables with mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables structure:

___Inventory

```
|--------|------------|----------|
| INV_Id | INV_Name   | INV_Rate |
|--------|------------|----------|
|     30 |  Breakfast |    15.00 |
|     31 |       Bike |    21.00 |
|     32 |      Visit |    19.00 |
|--------|------------|----------|
```

___SalesTaxes

```
|--------|--------------|------------|
| STX_Id | STX_TaxeName | STX_Amount |
|--------|--------------|------------|
|      8 |        Tax 1 |      5.000 |
|      9 |        Tax 2 |      5.000 |
|     10 |        Tax 3 |     19.975 |
|--------|--------------|------------|
```

*STX_Amount is a percentage.*

___ApplicableTaxesInventory

```
|-----------|-----------|
| ATX_INVId | ATX_STXId |
|-----------|-----------|
|        30 |         9 |
|        30 |        10 |
|        31 |         9 |
|-----------|-----------|
```

- ATX_INVId is the item ID link with ___Inventory.
- ATX_STXId is the tax ID link with ___SalesTaxes.

---

I need to list item from `___Inventory` and get these infos

So mething like this:

```
|--------|----------|----------|-----------|
| INV_Id | INV_Rate | Tax_List | sum_taxes |
|--------|----------|----------|-----------|
|     30 |    15.00 |     9,10 |    24.975 |
|     31 |    21.00 |        9 |     5.000 |
|     32 |    19.00 |          |           |
|--------|----------|----------|-----------|
```

---

My last try was this one:

```
SELECT *, 
(SELECT SUM(st.STX_Amount) 
FROM ___SalesTaxes st
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(st.STX_Id, ati.ATX_INVId) > 0) as sum_taxes
FROM  ___Inventory i 
INNER JOIN ___ApplicableTaxesInventory ati
    ON ___Inventory.INV_Id = ___ApplicableTaxesInventory.ATX_INVId
ORDER BY INV_Name ASC
```

Please see this SQLFiddle to help you if needed:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/622ea0/2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOINs` to ensure that you get rows for all inventory items even when there are no applicable taxes. Then a couple of `IFNULLs` to change `NULL` values into something more useful (unless you are happy with `NULL`):

```
SELECT
  INV_Id,
  INV_Name,
  IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(STX_Id), "") as `Tax_List`,
  INV_Rate,
  IFNULL(SUM(STX_Amount), 0)  as sum_taxes
FROM ___Inventory i
LEFT JOIN ___ApplicableTaxesInventory ati
ON ati.ATX_INVId = i.INV_Id
LEFT JOIN ___SalesTaxes st
ON st.STX_Id = ati.ATX_STXId
GROUP BY INV_Id
```

Output:

```
INV_Id  INV_Name    Tax_List    INV_Rate    sum_taxes
30      Breakfast   10,9        15          24.975
31      Bike rental 9           21          5
32      Visit                   19          0
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL Fiddle, you aliased the tables, but forgot to use the alias' where you referenced them:

```
SELECT *, 
(SELECT SUM(st.STX_Amount) 
FROM ___SalesTaxes st
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(st.STX_Id, ati.ATX_INVId) > 0) as sum_taxes
FROM  ___Inventory i 
INNER JOIN ___ApplicableTaxesInventory ati
    ON i.INV_Id = ati.ATX_INVId
ORDER BY INV_Name ASC
```

A better way to get what you are looking for is to join the tables together:

```
SELECT
  INV_Id,
  INV_Name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(STX_Id) as `Tax_List`,
  INV_Rate,
  SUM(STX_Amount) as sum_taxes
FROM ___Inventory i
JOIN ___ApplicableTaxesInventory ati
ON ati.ATX_INVId = i.INV_Id
JOIN ___SalesTaxes st
ON st.STX_Id = ati.ATX_STXId
GROUP BY INV_Id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/622ea0/8/0)**:

```
| INV_Id |    INV_Name | INV_Rate | sum_taxes |
|--------|-------------|----------|-----------|
|     30 |   Breakfast |       15 |    24.975 |
|     31 | Bike rental |       21 |         5 |
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It doesn't seem to make the same as my exemple. I have two times the same item and do not have the sum of the taxes. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/622ea0/3

Comment: If it works for you, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Then it needs a group by. What column(s) should be used to group for a sum of the taxes?

Comment: Hello. How to get the tax list please  ?

Comment: If you also want inventory items that do not have taxes, add ```LEFT ``` to the ```JOIN``` clauses. IOW, ```LEFT JOIN```

Comment: With your update do you know why it miss the Inventory #32 ‘Visit’ ? I should have it even if I do not have any tax for it.